# Thirst is the need to drink. Hunger is the need to eat. _____ is the need to get drunk

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word describing the need to get drunk/intoxicated?

Comment: Yeah, it's alcohol addiction.

Comment: Alcoholism is comparative to obesity in the OP example.

Comment: @tinyDragon - A comment like that should have been made in a more fleshed-out question, not left as a comment to a suggested answer.

Comment: I'm starting to get a feeling that people here are more obsessed with the format, rather the content. Good to know.

Comment: It's a false analogy. Water and food are necessities of life; drunkenness is not. There's no specific term for the urgent desire to read a novel or play a game or break into song, either (or maybe there is, but not something as common as "hunger" and "thirst" and presumably without any implication that you'll die if the "need" is not eventually satisfied).

Comment: Uh, no. Thirst and hunger have physical manifestations. Just wanting a beer afer work isn't a need, unless a psychological one. The only people who feel an actual physical need for alcohol are alcohol-dependent.

Comment: @tinyDragon - It's not so much a matter of "obsessed with the format, rather than the content." It's a matter of, when a question is very vague and scant on details, you're a lot more likely to get answers that aren't helpful. Additional information helps us help you.

Comment: I think "politics" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: **Sobriety** is the need to get drunk. :P

Comment: @tinyDragon Please see the [tag info for single-word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). The comments so far and the answer you have rejected could have been avoided if the question was worded to be more specific about what you are looking for. *You* obviously know: help others to know, too.

Answer (score 2):

***[Alcholism:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alcoholism)***

> continued excessive or compulsive use of alcoholic drinks.

(M-W)

Comment: Should have been a comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - why? I think it is the answer OP is looking for,

Comment: Because the OP has shown no effort, no research...

Comment: I think it's a related word, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's "the answer the OP is looking for." **Hunger : Eating :: Alcoholism : Getting Drunk** – is that an apt analogy? I don't see it as exact fit.

Comment: @J.R. I said  ***I think*** it is the answer OP is looking for. You are welcome to post your own if you like.

Comment: I said ***I think*** it's a related word. You weighed in with an opinion, and so did I.

Comment: Alcoholism is definitely not what I was looking for. You can't for instance say " I am so Alcoholism" like you can with " I'm so thirsty"

Comment: @tinyDragon - alcholism  fits in the sentence exemple you show in your question.  “I am so...” is a different sentence. “*I am so addicted to alcool that ....*”

Comment: @user2922582 not directly. Alcoholism is the need to get drunk, but it's not THE only definition of the word. It's a condition, rather than purely an impulse like with hunger or thirst. But you are right, I should have constructed my question differently.

Comment: @tinyDragon - I suggest you make a clearer question. Note that “the need to get drunk/intoxicated”  implies an addiction to some substance.

Comment: _Thirst_ is usually used to mean thirst for alcohol, in context. It's not like you need another verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler - this is interesting, but that’s a cultural issue, I suppose.

Comment: 2 words: physiological withdrawal